# Move data from Splunk to Elastic Search

Tags: database, elasticsearch, transfer, splunk

I have a script in splunk which runs in regular intervals and puts data in the Splunk. Now i want to transfer this data to Elastic Search also. So the data gets input in both splunk and Elastic Search. Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Spring Data Elasticsearch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/) in Java, and [Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/) with [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), you could set up a batch job that reads in data from the [Splunk REST API](http://dev.splunk.com/restapi), and writes the data into an Elasticsearch index.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to let Splunk do this for you. The most applicable could be the export command, which can export Splunk data in JSON format, which is what Elasticsearch requires. Export can be run via CLI, REST, the Splunk SDKs, or manually via the Web UI. [doc link](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.5.0/Search/Exportsearchresults)